# MYSQL/PHP Wont update

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which doesn't work for some reason

```
    $con = mysql_connect("$server", "$user", "$pass");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db('$db', $con); 

 // BLOCK 1   
    $supplier=$_POST["supplier"];
    $supplierNowBalance =$_POST["supplierNowBalance"];
    $supplierBalance=$supplierNowBalance - $supplier; 


    mysql_query("UPDATE inv SET balance='".$supplierBalance."' WHERE username='supplier' AND name='bingo'");

    echo $supplierBalance;

// END OF BLOCK 1
```

Everything before and after the UPDATE statement works. I copied the update statement to PHPMyAdmin and it updates just fine! I don't get it. for some reason php is not running the mysql_query

Few tips: I have few of this block of code in the program so it goes through all of them posts and calculates, and updates
 I have tried every possible combination for the mysql query (with and without 's )

###############ANSWER_***_*__*_*__*_*__**

Thanks for the answer but I figured it out. Apparently PHP is desperate to have double quote "" around the connection string.
On line 6, when I descrbed the database variable

```
mysql_select_db('$db', $con);
```

I had single qoute, I changed it to double qoute and bam, it worked, Thanks

```
 mysql_select_db("$db", $con);
```

Comment: Sanity check: `$res = mysql_query("UPDATE inv...."); if (!$res) die(mysql_error());`  If that doesn't die, then check `mysql_affected_rows($res);` to see how many rows were updated.  It will likely yield 0 if you have a problem.  BTW, you are vulnerable to SQL injection with the code the way it is.  Use `mysql_real_escape_string` on user input data and also consider switching to PDO or Mysqli as `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: You could lose the *double quote* as well. `mysql_select_db($db, $con);` would work all the same.

Comment: To further clarify what Majid said, PHP isn't *desperate* to have the double quotes, it's because when you are using single quotes you are literally telling it to use the database "dollar sign, letter d, letter b" which is probably not the name of your database.

Answer (score 2):

`balance` is `numeric` right? you shouldn't wrap it with single quotes.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE inv SET balance= " . $supplierBalance . " WHERE username='supplier' AND name='bingo'");
```

using **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** makes it invulnerable with `SQL INJECTION`

```
<?php

// other codes

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE inv SET balance = ? WHERE username = ? AND name = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $supplierBalance);
$stmt->bindParam(2, 'supplier');
$stmt->bindParam(3, 'bingo');

$stmt->execute();

// other codes
?>
```

Comment: I post the answer under my question, although it didnt matter when I put it in qoutation too, it worked both ways as long as it was in correct format

Comment: *Shouldn't*, or *don't have to*?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer but I figured it out. Apparently PHP is desperate to have double quote "" around the connection string.
On line 6, when I descrbed the database variable

```
mysql_select_db('$db', $con);
```

I had single qoute, I changed it to double qoute and bam, it worked, Thanks

```
 mysql_select_db("$db", $con);
```